# Gmail API best way to retrieve message list with already included metadata

Tags: php, laravel, gmail-api

I'm trying to retrieve gmail messages using `Gmail API` and Laravel's `HTTP Facade`.

I noticed that `users.messages.list` only returns the message's `id` and `threadId`, I understand they did this to make the retrieval faster.

The problem with this is that, In my use-case, I wanted to retrieve each message's `payload>headers: name="From" and name="To"` to get the sender and the receiver's email address and later group the result by receiver's email address.

Now, what I did was, Initially call the `users.messages.list` by using `GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages`. Now I have access to every message's `id`.

Next, I then loop through the list and create a new property called `meta` and store the return value of `users.messages.get` using `GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{id}`

My code looks like this:

```
$list = collect((Http::withToken($user->token)
        ->get('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myemail@mydomain.com/messages'))->json()); 

// $list returns {messages: [{id: 12313, threadId: 15151}, {id: 215151, threadId: 12778}, ...]}

$final_list = $list->map(function ($value) {
    $value['meta'] = Http::withToken($user->token)
                     ->get('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myemail@mydomain.com/messages/{$message_id}');
    return $value;
})

// $final list should return {messages: [{id: 12313, threadId: 15151, meta: {...}}, {id: 215151, threadId: 12778, meta: {...}}, ...]}
```

Now, with this approach gave me error saying:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

I undestand that it gives this error, because each messages contain base64 format of the email's body message. Making it very heavy. I can exclude the base64 from the payload by using `metadata` scope, BUT by doing this, I wont be able to specify the `q` query parameter filters.

My question is that, is there a way to only retrieve the metadata without using metadata in the auth scope?

OR

Are there any optimal way of achieving the same result(same in the $final_result sample result)?

Comment: check out this [partial-response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance#partial-response) you can add fields parameter to limit the response that is returned to only the fields you want.

Comment: @DaImTo I guess this is the optimal way of doing it, at the moment. It only reduces the execution time to 3 ~ 5 secs tho.

Comment: This is the way it is. its a free api you may need to accept that the issue is not with your code.

Comment: Have you considered increasing the allowed runtime or changing the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` for the script? There is also a `set_time_limit` function to limit the execution time: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @Kessy, I think I won't bother with that. I'm more concerned on how fast it retrieves the list. Maybe I will just run it on background and queue them by batch.